# Android thumbnail when it goes to background

Tags: android, android-layout, onpause

I have an app in android that I want to protect it's content when the app goes to background or mainly when the user pressed on the home button. If I go to switching between apps I can see a small thumbnail there of my current app screen, which I want to protect it with some blur or another screen.

I tried blurring, dimming, changing colour in the onPause event, but it always takes the screenshot thumbnail for the switch apps as it is.

Do you have any idea or approach on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried disabling the thumbnail by adding `FLAG_SECURE` to your window on exiting?

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works... any idea if instead of the black screen we can put a custom screen there?

Comment: I wouldn't know much about that but apparently it's not possible right now. Then again i might be wrong.